# A more elegant way to return a list of node values from depth-first recursive function in Python 3?

Tags: python, optimization, binary-tree

I'm working out how to return a list of values from a depth-first traversal of a binary tree. Specifically, I'm trying to do so with a recursive function.

After playing around a bit I got this code to properly return the list of expected values, but using a try/finally block in order to pull it off seems clunky to me.

```
def depth_first_recursive(root, node_list: list):
    try:
        if not root:
            return
        else:
            node_list.append(root.val)
            depth_first_recursive(root.left, node_list)
            depth_first_recursive(root.right, node_list)
    finally:
        return node_list


class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        values = []


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Node('a')
    b = Node('b')
    c = Node('c')
    d = Node('d')
    e = Node('e')
    f = Node('f')

    a.left = b
    a.right = c
    b.left = d
    b.right = e
    c.right = f

    nodelist = []
    print(depth_first_recursive(a, node_list=nodelist))
```

returns `['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'f', ]`

Is there a better way to pull this off in Python?

Comment: Note there are several traversals that could be considered depth-first; this one is a pre-order traversal, since you record a node in the output before any of its descendants.

Comment: Hmm, the better way is so much easier to come up with than this. I'm confused.

Comment: @KellyBundy I'm a student and in the hacky phase of programming. I brute forced this until something worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplified yours, much more efficient than all the copying of the others. Yours takes O(n) time, theirs is O(n²).

```
def depth_first_recursive(root, node_list: list):
    if root:
        node_list.append(root.val)
        depth_first_recursive(root.left, node_list)
        depth_first_recursive(root.right, node_list)
    return node_list
```

Answer (score 0):

I have applied the same logic as yours but tried to make code compact:

```
def depth_first_recursive(root, node_list: list):
    if root is None: return []
    return [root.val]+depth_first_recursive(root.left, node_list) + depth_first_recursive(root.right, node_list)
```

Output:

> ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'f']

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to maintain a `node_list`, just have more faith in the structure of your recursion.

```
def depth_first_recursive(root):

    if root is None:
        return []
    # Terminal case when reaching bottom of tree
    elif not root.left and not root.right:
        return [root.val]
    # Get current value and continue to append list
    else:
        return [root.val] + depth_first_recursive(root.left) + depth_first_recursive(root.right)
```